# pasting images from an array to a bigger image

Tags: python, arrays, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory

This is my program, I'm trying for a 1x2 array of two cv2 images to past it to a bigger one. the idea is to do that for a bigger array of images and see them as a mosaic.
Problem is that this seems a mixture of cv2 and PIL and couldn't manage it to work.
Here my little code:

```
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import cm

#example of one of the two images added
new_array = cv2.resize(x_test[0], (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
trp.append(new_array2)

im_pil=[]
#I create the big image
new_im = Image.new('RGB', (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE * 2))

k=0
#here i want to place my image in the mosaic
for i in range(0,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE):
    for j in range(0,IMG_SIZE *2,IMG_SIZE):
        #paste the image at location i,j:

        im_pil.append(Image.fromarray(trp[k])
        new_im.paste(im_pil[k], (i,j))
        k+=1

new_im
```

that's all the code( a little summarized) and I don't really know where the problem is. I get different kinds of errors in each modification, from invalid syntax to not defined or some crazy ones i dont understand.
although that

```
plt.imshow(trp[1])
plt.show()
```

works and shows one image

I'm sorry if the answer is obvious buy I'm trying my best to figure it out and I can't manage it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have only one image in trp and you use `k += 1` and never check if `k` is biggere then `len(trp)` - so you probably get error with `List Index`

Comment: It's unclear whether you want to use just PIL or just OpenCV. It's unclear how big and how many your images are, whether they are transparent or not and where you want to paste them. A diagram might help. And some images.

Comment: I don't know why do you use list `im_pil`. Maybe you should put `Image.fromarray(trp[k])` directly in `paste()` or you could create it after resizing image and when you append it to `trp`. BTW: you forgot last `)` in `im_pil.append(...)`

Comment: do you need `cv2` ? You can resize iamge using `PIL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you use `cv2` because you can do all in `PIL`. You can even display it without `matplot`

```
from PIL import Image

IMG_SIZE = 128

filenames = ['image1.png', 'image2.png']
images = []

for name in filenames:

    img = Image.open(name)
    img = img.resize((IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))

    images.append(img)

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE*2))

k = 0
for i in range(0, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE):
    for j in range(0, IMG_SIZE *2, IMG_SIZE):
        new_im.paste(images[k], (i,j))
        k += 1

new_im.save('output.png')
new_im.show()
```

---

For images from `cv2` you have to

- convert colors from `BGR` to `RGB`
- convert `array` to `Image`
- do what you want
- convert back `Image` to `array`
- if you want to use again with `cv2` then convert colors from `RGB` to `BGR`

Code:

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

IMG_SIZE = 128

filenames = ['image1.png', 'image2.png']

images = []

for name in filenames:

    im = cv2.imread(name)
    im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    im = cv2.resize(im, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))

    img = Image.fromarray(im)
    images.append(img)

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE*2))

k = 0
for i in range(0, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE):
    for j in range(0, IMG_SIZE *2, IMG_SIZE):
        new_im.paste(images[k], (i,j))
        k += 1

im = np.array(new_im)        

plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()

#cv2.imshow('window', cv2.cvtColor(np.array(new_im), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
#cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly. I didn't know i could use PIL for all, thanks to this I also arranged some of other codes. Thanks for sharing the code